# How to centre menu of Wordpress website without effecting mobile menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

I've centred the top menu of my wordpress website www.theestablishmenthairdresing.com to make sure that the top menu does not overlap with the logo on the left when the browser window size is reduced using the following code:

```
nav#site-navigation.main-navigation {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 80em;
}
```

However, now when I check the mobile menu for the website the sub-menu drop down option for "About" do not appear on the mobile version, please see screenshots:

Before adding code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMoqv.jpg

After adding code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbcQJ.jpg

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'xyz' ); ?></button>

                    <div id="site-header-menu" class="site-header-menu">
                        <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) : ?>
                            <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Primary Menu', 'xyz' ); ?>">
                                <?php
                                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                                        'theme_location' => 'primary',
                                        'menu_class'     => 'primary-menu',
                                     ) );
                                ?>
                            </nav><!-- .main-navigation -->
```